# How to pass a list object from one page to another

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm struggling to pass a list of objects from one page to another. Object data is  displayed on the first page, but I can switch to another page if I want to display more details about objects.

When I click on the Back button on another page, I would like to go back to the first page and still got the same list so I can show all filtered objects again without querying them again from DB.

I have checked the documentation of passing values but I can't do that with list:

1. Method expression (JSF 2.0)
2. f:param
3. f:attribute
4. f:setPropertyActionListener

Is it with list object possible? Can someone give me example?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe instead of passing things on, using a deltaspike `@ViewAccessScoped` is easier. It will keep something in scope untill it is not accessed by a new view.

Comment: but these 2 different views/pages do not use the same backing bean. When i use ViewAccessScoped i always get java.lang.NullPointerException and my app doesnt work anymore...

Comment: Did you add DeltaSpike to your project? And you should be using CDI `@Named` then instead of  `@ManagedBean` (forgot to state this since I'm already so used to using cdi instead of jsf manage beans). Different backingbeans is not the problem if you make the list a separate managed bean and inject that. It will work then.